# Oracle ADF - Redirect link is not working

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a simple application using ADF comes with basic CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete). In this case, as you can see, I have dragged a link to the 1st column which is highlighted in yellow.

[image]

So whenever I deploy it and click that, it is supposed to redirect me to the `Edit` page where client will allow to make commit:

[image]

I did make sure the `Action` of link  is associated with the `Edit` page (as highlighted in yellow above). However, the `link` wouldn't redirect me anywhere, no response.This is the unbounded task flow:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have found out the solution. Due to the default setting, the application will be deployed on IE and this message will prompt out. As you can see, the message is mentioning about browser's compatibility. My IE is version 11.6, I'm not sure what's the issue here since my IE is kinda latest version but this message still pops out and affects the redirect link from working. However, simply copy the application URL to Google Chrome and run should fix this issue. Hope this helps in future.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the two pages in the Unbounded Task Flow, then Add **WildCard Control Flow Rule** 
and connect the two pages with the WildCard.

[image]

Or you can use the **Popup** instead of opening a new page for edit

Comment: I just don't get it...it suppose to work as what I did for the task flow. Still figure it out why it isn't working.

Comment: Check the property PartialSubmit is it True Value for the link

Comment: Default was `false` for PartialSubmit. I switched it to true and it's still not working. I tried to change my task flow too, use method call `ExecuteWithParams` as connector between two `View` to pass the parameters. Still nope.

Comment: Make sure when you are selecting the action value it comes automatically to select  (edit) So you do not need to fill it manually, Otherwise means the action is not exists. also the immediate property should equals false

Comment: Yep the action comes automatically whenever I associate it with control flow case. Properties `Disabled`,`Immediate` and `Blocking` are equal false. It just wouldn't work...